# How to flatten a list of objects containing a list and pass each element into a method?

Tags: java, java-stream

Given the following entity:

```java
public class Parent extends {
    private Long id;    
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I am attempting to learn how to use the Java 8 Stream API to flatten a `List<Parent>`, each containing a `List<Child>` and pass the stream of `Child` into a void method.

For example:

```java
List<Parent> parents = //..

schedules.stream()
        .flatMap(Parent::getChildren)
        .forEach(this::invoke);
```

This gives the error:

> Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert java.util.List< Child > to java.util.stream.Stream < ? extends R >

Comment: You flatMap to a stream. So `.flatMap(parent -> parent.getChildren().stream())`

Comment: Also I think that if the children of that first operation have any children themselves, no flat map construct will recursively invoke `getChildren`.  It's one level of children only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Stream.flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) requires a `Function` which returns a `Stream` as parameter. You are trying to pass a `Function` which returns a `List`. Use this instead:

```
List<Parent> parents = ...;
parents.stream()
        .flatMap(p -> p.getChildren().stream())
        .forEach(this::invoke);
```

Alternatively you can use `Stream.map()` and `Stream.flatMap()`:

```
parents.stream()
        .map(Parent::getChildren)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .forEach(this::invoke);
```